# SignalR Delay firing OnDisconnected in Hub

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

When I navigate away from a page in Silverlight I call a function in Javascript which contains the following:

> $.connection.hub.stop();

In my Hub class I override  `OnDisconnected()`

Usually, the OnDisconnected event fires, but sometimes it doesn't fire and it takes seemingly various amounts of time before it times out and the OnDisconnected is fired.

After I navigate away from the page that creates the connection, Fiddler shows that the original signalr/connect?... request has no response code (the column shows '-', and the Body column shows '-1) - Shouldn't this return 200?

[image: After navigating to the page, then away, then back again and sitting there]

If I navigate back to the page, a new connection is established.

Sometimes a signalr/abort request is issued, passing the same connectionToken, but the original connect request remains the same (open).
[image: With abort request]

Why isn't the OnDisconnected event firing immediately every time in the hub, since the connection is being stopped explicitly in the client?

Using SignalR 1.2.1 .NET 4.0

Having read [the documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#onreconnected), I don't believe this applies to my situation:

> The OnDisconnected method doesn't get called in some scenarios, such as when a server goes down or the App Domain gets recycled. When another server comes on line or the App Domain completes its recycle, some clients may be able to reconnect and fire the OnReconnected event.